# how to avoid double on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, filter, double

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

As you can see on image NOID 29 already taken by LIB_TOURNE 1, how can i neglect the NOID 29 that taken by LIB_TOURNE 2

so when NOID with date X is unique. NOID 29 with date 2012-09-27 11:47:52.000 only appear once time.

[image]

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

PS : i have try also:

> SELECT DISTINCT  * FROM LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL  LEFT JOIN TOURNE ON
>   LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.INSEE_DEST = TOURNE.NO_INSEE AND TYPE_TOURNE =
>   MODE_LIV  order by TOURNE.LIB_TOURNE

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Choose when a Noid repeated, the one who has the minor Lib_Tourne ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `group by`:

```
select min(lib_tourne), <all columns but lib_tourne>
from (<your query here>) t
group by <all columns but lib_tourne>
```

Comment: thanks you very much...you help my day, by the way why you use min function ?